# How to continue uploading in the background of the iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

I have iOS app that is main functionality is to upload images.
My question is there any case that app can continue uploading images and communicate with server when app is dismissed?

Thanks

Comment: the phrase 'dismiss' means being _terminated_ or going to _background_?

Comment: @holex going to background.

Comment: @user3374800 : any luck with my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `NSURLConnection`, you can use a `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` to keep your connection alive even when the app is sent to background :

Declare your background task identifier so you can access it anywhere within your class implementation, for example at the top of your .m file :

```
@implementation MyClass {

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskID;
}
```

Create your connection :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: aURL];

NSURLConnection *uploadConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

backgroundTaskID = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

    // Cancel the connection in case of expiration
    [uploadConnection cancel];
}];
```

End your background task in both of these `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods after the connection completed / failed :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    // Handle a fail

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskID];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    // Handle a success

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskID];
}
```

Comment: Do we have to set any UIBackgroundModes for this?

Comment: Not a 100% reliable answer, but I'm pretty sure you don't need to.

Comment: I think so too, but I just did this for one client and he says that upload still fails if he goes to background.. tnx anyway